# Ruby regex, is there a way to only match literal matches?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to parse using a case/when statement with regex in it. I'm having some trouble with the match as it will give me a match even if it's not a literal match.

Example:

if I input ($45, x), I get back: "address mode: indirect, x -> value: 45" from this regex:

```
/[(][$][1-9a-fA-F]{1,2}\s*,\s*[xX]\s*[)]/
```

Now, if I input ($45, p), I get a match for this regex:

```
/[$][1-9a-fA-F]{2,4}/
```

Which is understandable, but I would like the match to look only for literal matches. If there are extra characters that does not exactly match the regex I want the match function to return false.

Is there some other functions like match() or extra arguments that can be given to match() to get this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question, it is a little unclear what you are after. Your second regex is matching on the substring

```
$45
```

If you want to avoid this, use the anchors ^ and $ to ensure the entire string is matched. Something like:

```
^\(\$[1-9A-Za-z]+,\s*[xX]\s*\)$
```

Comment: The `^` and `$` anchors match the beginning and end of lines. To make sure the entire string matches the regex, use `\A` and `\Z` instead